# Could I catch React SyntheticEvent before Native DOM Event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to catch React component's SyntheticEvent on native DOM element.

https://jsfiddle.net/xwh6dyur/2/

This code generate following DOM elements.

```
<div id="not-react-dom-outer">
  <div id="not-react-dom-inner">
    <div id="container">
      <div data-reactid=".0">
        <button data-reactid=".0.0">react button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected event order below in accordance with normal Event bubbling.

1. button(react component)
2. div#not-react-dom-inner
3. div#not-react-dom-outer

but, actually is below.

1. div#not-react-dom-inner
2. div#not-react-dom-outer
3. button(react component)

I want to catch React SyntheticEvent before Native DOM Event.
Are there any good methodologies for that?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: I'm trying to moving from backbone view to react component.

Comment: if you're interested in catching native events, there's a `nativeEvent` prop on the React event.

Comment: sorry, I've posted on the way. Deteal is following. On its way I encountered a obstacles. Parent backbone view has use stopPropagation on own click event handler. So I haven't be able to catch react component event....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React event handler isn't actually bound to `button`, the event handler listening at the root of the React document, that's why the order in which these callbacks fire might not be as expected.